# CounterStrike: Global Offensive automatic reload

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

After holding down the fire button and depleting a clip, the gun will not automatically reload until the fire button is released.

Is this behavior by design, or is it a problem with my setup? MOUSE1 is bound to the "Fire" action, and Raw Mouse Input is disabled.

Comment: Just because other games do it, it doesn't mean all other games have the same mechanic.

Comment: Are you implying that this behavior is by design? If so, consider posting an answer instead of downvoting the question and leaving a derogatory comment.

Comment: Pretty sure it's supposed to be like that; most games do that so you don't just hold down the fire key.

Comment: @fbueckert I don't think TF2, L4D* or HL* work like this to be fair.

Answer (score 4):

All iterations of the counter-strike games have functioned this way since the initial release.

Simply because other games use a different mechanic does not imply that all games do.

In Counter-Strike, the time you choose to reload your gun is a very strategic one, having it "auto-reload" takes away this mechanic.